# Intelligent git stash and rebase

Tags: git

In our repo (because its large) doing a rebase is painful, we all work our own master branch, commit locally, fetch, rebase, then push, mostly we end up doing

```
git fetch
git stash
git rebase
git stash pop
git push
```

This process can take 30-60 seconds (mostly its aliased into 1 command)

During this time its really hands off the keyboard because if you touch any files you can cause "unstaged changes" and the rebase to fail

People very often have working copies of unstaged files not part of any commit yet (hence the need for the stash)

If you are using visual studio, you see visual studio asking if you want to reload files (as it moves your files out of the way and back again)

Its all a little annoying...and a little bit error prone. I wondered if there is a better way:

1. Given that you have just done a git fetch you know the
   origin/master commit
2. You know your own HEAD commit
3. You'd think it might be possible to stash ONLY those files which are
   part of the commits between your current commit and the
   origin/master commit
4. It feels there is no need to stash any files which are not going to
   need to be merged

I've also noticed that when stash moves an unstaged files out of the way and back again (which is not modified by the rebase) it changes the modification time of the file. If you have a build system which works on dependencies then it will cause those touched files to need rebuilding

So my question:

1. is it possible to do a limited (affected files only) stash?
2. is it possible for stash pop to retain the modification times from when they were stashed?
3. is there a better way of working?

Many thanks in advance

Additional Information... a large portion of the time is taken up with the stash and stash pop

Total Stash Time     = 17:17:52.883984 - 17:16:34.682266 = 1 minutes, 18 seconds
Total Stash Pop Time = 17:19:25.326706 - 17:18:23.357639 = 1 minutes, 2 seconds

```
$ GIT_TRACE=true git stash
17:16:34.682266 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-stash
17:16:34.683120 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-stash
17:16:35.392884 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:16:35.394043 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:16:35.574243 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:16:35.575410 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:16:35.902034 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
17:16:36.104332 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects
17:16:36.499926 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-prefix
17:16:36.679648 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
17:16:36.890647 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path index
17:16:37.083861 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get-colorbool color.interactive
17:16:37.251940 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get-color color.interactive.help 'red bold'
17:16:37.421967 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get-color  reset
17:16:37.594741 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --sq --prefix src/mydir --
17:16:37.779674 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git ls-files --error-unmatch --
17:16:38.055453 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git update-index -q --refresh
17:16:51.868211 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD --ignore-submodules --
17:16:52.292151 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules --
17:17:05.488052 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git reflog exists refs/stash
17:17:05.679272 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git update-index -q --refresh
17:17:18.769370 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-index --quiet --cached HEAD --ignore-submodules --
17:17:19.147722 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-files --quiet --ignore-submodules --
17:17:32.039258 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify HEAD
17:17:32.322507 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-list --oneline -n 1 HEAD --
17:17:32.721850 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git symbolic-ref -q HEAD
17:17:32.963491 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git write-tree
17:17:33.479251 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git commit-tree 2372528ce6a7cf773c3e7df932ea1762f69459e4 -p 270db9ff224e8b7baaa76f3f12dc55cf04dd7c5f
17:17:33.842338 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git read-tree --index-output=.git/index.stash.31348 -m 2372528ce6a7cf773c3e7df932ea1762f69459e4
17:17:35.405659 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-index --name-only -z HEAD --
17:17:50.044073 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git update-index -z --add --remove --stdin
17:17:50.788781 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git write-tree
17:17:51.617735 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git commit-tree 4af893fdd10d58762651befa2bbb8eee71f291ac -p 270db9ff224e8b7baaa76f3f12dc55cf04dd7c5f -p 323f7da91a6ddfe52f0346d3e3fa6506cfde0fbb
17:17:51.938857 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git update-ref --create-reflog -m 'WIP on master: 270db9ff224 Mylastcommit' refs/stash da808c64188e12626e92107d95433f507415e053
17:17:52.380955 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'Saved working directory and index state $stash_msg'
17:17:52.382510 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'Saved working directory and index state $stash_msg'
17:17:52.619887 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'Saved working directory and index state $stash_msg'
17:17:52.621484 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'Saved working directory and index state $stash_msg'
Saved working directory and index state WIP on master: 270db9ff224 Mylastcommit
17:17:52.883984 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git reset --hard -q
```

The stash pop

```
$ GIT_TRACE=true git stash pop
17:18:23.357639 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-stash pop
17:18:23.358544 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-stash pop
17:18:25.532417 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:18:25.535394 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:18:26.782965 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:18:26.786540 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'usage: $dashless $USAGE'
17:18:30.387292 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-dir
17:18:30.846062 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path objects
17:18:31.444631 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-prefix
17:18:31.688101 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --show-toplevel
17:18:31.958273 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --git-path index
17:18:32.214299 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get-colorbool color.interactive
17:18:32.505740 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get-color color.interactive.help 'red bold'
17:18:32.894387 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git config --get-color  reset
17:18:33.251394 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify --quiet refs/stash
17:18:33.571029 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --symbolic --verify --quiet 'refs/stash@{0}'
17:18:33.883359 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify --quiet 'refs/stash@{0}^2'
17:18:34.655407 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --symbolic-full-name refs/stash
17:18:34.842979 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify --quiet 'refs/stash@{0}^3'
17:18:35.180608 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git update-index -q --refresh
17:18:50.084605 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git write-tree
17:18:50.728293 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git merge-recursive 2372528ce6a7cf773c3e7df932ea1762f69459e4 -- 2372528ce6a7cf773c3e7df932ea1762f69459e4 4af893fdd10d58762651befa2bbb8eee71f291ac
17:18:53.083985 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git diff-index --cached --name-only --diff-filter=A 2372528ce6a7cf773c3e7df932ea1762f69459e4
17:18:53.875222 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git read-tree --reset 2372528ce6a7cf773c3e7df932ea1762f69459e4
17:18:55.686552 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git update-index --add --stdin
17:18:56.025110 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git status
On branch master
Your branch is up to date with 'origin/master'.

Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

        modified:   ....
        ....

Untracked files:
  (use "git add <file>..." to include in what will be committed)

        ....


It took 13.53 seconds to enumerate untracked files. 'status -uno'
may speed it up, but you have to be careful not to forget to add
new files yourself (see 'git help status').
no changes added to commit (use "git add" and/or "git commit -a")
17:19:24.442842 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git reflog delete --updateref --rewrite 'refs/stash@{0}'
17:19:24.783530 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'Dropped ${REV} ($s)'
17:19:24.785203 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst --variables 'Dropped ${REV} ($s)'
17:19:25.045532 git.c:576               trace: exec: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'Dropped ${REV} ($s)'
17:19:25.047257 run-command.c:640       trace: run_command: git-sh-i18n--envsubst 'Dropped ${REV} ($s)'
Dropped refs/stash@{0} (da808c64188e12626e92107d95433f507415e053)
17:19:25.326706 git.c:344               trace: built-in: git rev-parse --verify --quiet 'refs/stash@{0}'

Total Stash Pop Time = 17:19:25.326706 - 17:18:23.357639 = 1 minutes, 2 seconds
```

When I did a recent update I realized it was taking 3-4 minutes to do the complete stash/rebase/pop

I'm even using the new builtin rebase and stash to try and speed things up

https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/pull/1800 and git v2.20

```
[rebase]
    useBuiltin = true
[stash]
    useBuiltin = true
```

and other best practices

(e.g. my disk is an SSD)

```
[core]
    preloadindex = true
    fscache = true
```

Comment: Regarding the third question: Why do you rebase all the time? Couldn't you simply merge changes into the master (or a feature branch), see https://nvie.com/posts/a-successful-git-branching-model/?

Comment: Yes we do rebase all the time..I don't think that was a conscious decision or is in anyway set in stone, just the way we decided to work to avoid issues, we don't use branches we do our development in our local master and push them to origin, this though was deliberate to prevent people going off in a branch only to land a huge piece of work in one go.

Comment: I should have said, we don't like merge commits.. so "git pull" to merge the changes is not good for us...

Comment: One alternative to stashing could be to create a temporary commit with your current changes. Ie. do something like `git add -A && git commit -m "Tmp commit" && git pull --rebase origin master`. After the rebase, either continue working and use `git commit --amend` to update the tmp commit when you finish working on the current changes, or `git reset --soft HEAD^` to remove the tmp commmit, but keep those changes in your work tree. With this workflow, the non-conflicting files should not be touched in your work-tree.

Comment: @sauerburger I worked on a team before that always rebased rather than merged in order to get rid of that extra merge commit (and to squash any commits if there's more than one during your development)

Comment: @Alderath I may try that...feels like it would be quicker

Comment: "to avoid issues", and how did that work out for you?

Comment: _we don't use branches_ **yes you do**. You've just decided to all give your branches the same name. Different local working copies of master are still, in practice, different branches. You haven't avoided branching and merging, you've just obfuscated them.

Comment: which OS do you use? If it is Windows, have you tried the native rebase and stash in recent git versions?